# How to update dataframe column value while joinining with other dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have 3 Dataframe `df1(EMPLOYEE_INFO),df2(DEPARTMENT_INFO),df3(COMPANY_INFO)` and i want to update a column which is in df1 by joining all the three dataframes . The name of column is FLAG_DEPARTMENT which is in df1. I need to set the `FLAG_DEPARTMENT='POLITICS'`  . In sql query will look like this.

```sql
UPDATE [COMPANY_INFO] INNER JOIN ([DEPARTMENT_INFO] 
INNER JOIN [EMPLOYEE_INFO] ON [DEPARTMENT_INFO].DEPT_ID = [EMPLOYEE_INFO].DEPT_ID)
ON [COMPANY_INFO].[COMPANY_DEPT_ID] = [DEPARTMENT_INFO].[DEP_COMPANYID]
SET EMPLOYEE_INFO.FLAG_DEPARTMENT = "POLITICS";
```

If the values in columns of these three tables matches i need to set my FLAG_DEPARTMENT='POLITICS' in my employee_Info Table

How can i achieve this same thing in pyspark. I have just started learning pyspark don't have that much depth knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a chain of `join`s with a `select` on top of it.

Suppose that you have the following pyspark `DataFrame`s:

```bash
employee_df
+---------+-------+
|     Name|dept_id|
+---------+-------+
|     John| dept_a|
|      Liù| dept_b|
|     Luke| dept_a|
|  Michail| dept_a|
|      Noe| dept_e|
|Shinchaku| dept_c|
|     Vlad| dept_e|
+---------+-------+

department_df
+-------+----------+------------+
|dept_id|company_id| description|
+-------+----------+------------+
| dept_a|  company1|Department A|
| dept_b|  company2|Department B|
| dept_c|  company5|Department C|
| dept_d|  company3|Department D|
+-------+----------+------------+

company_df
+----------+-----------+
|company_id|description|
+----------+-----------+
|  company1|  Company 1|
|  company2|  Company 2|
|  company3|  Company 3|
|  company4|  Company 4|
+----------+-----------+
```

Then you can run the following code to add the `flag_department` column to your `employee_df`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

employee_df = (
        employee_df.alias('a')
        .join(
            department_df.alias('b'),
            on='dept_id',
            how='left',
        )
        .join(
            company_df.alias('c'),
            on=F.col('b.company_id') == F.col('c.company_id'),
            how='left',
        )
        .select(
            *[F.col(f'a.{c}') for c in employee_df.columns],
            F.when(
                F.col('b.dept_id').isNotNull() & F.col('c.company_id').isNotNull(),
                F.lit('POLITICS')
            ).alias('flag_department')
        )
    )
```

The new `employee_df` will be:

```bash
+---------+-------+---------------+
|     Name|dept_id|flag_department|
+---------+-------+---------------+
|     John| dept_a|       POLITICS|
|      Liù| dept_b|       POLITICS|
|     Luke| dept_a|       POLITICS|
|  Michail| dept_a|       POLITICS|
|      Noe| dept_e|           null|
|Shinchaku| dept_c|           null|
|     Vlad| dept_e|           null|
+---------+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: hi @PieCot what will happen if in employee_df column name is DEPT_ID and in Department_df column name is DEPARTMENT_IDS

Comment: in this case we cannot directly join

Comment: You can change the clause`on`  in the first join: `on=F.col('a.DEPT_ID') == F.col('b.DEPARTMENT_IDS')`

Comment: Hi bro if i remove the second join and use select with first join only then also it works right for updating the empdf

Comment: Perfect! Depending on the condition you want for the update, both work :)